# Allow a user to modify a label on my webpage

Tags: reactjs

So full disclosure, I am relatively new to React so I am still very much a noob.

I am trying to create a web-page that contains virtual post-it notes.  The part I am struggling with is that I would like to allow the user to click on different parts of the page and change the Title, board titles and post it note text.  I am trying to find a elegant way to do this other than just using a brute-force onClick method.  I was hoping to maybe get some other approaches on how I can use react to easily handle something like this.

[image]

Comment: What's a "brute-force `onClick` method"? I would assume each note is a component. Each component has a title area. Clicking on that title area would make it editable. Clicks are handled with `onClick` (or equivalent).

Comment: Good question - What I mean by that is that I would expect that when a user clicks on a tag that I would need to adjust the style of the tag handle all of the input and then return the style back to the default once it has been adjusted.  It just doesn't seem like a elegant solution to me, but maybe its the best way.

Yes all notes are components and all the boards are their own components.

Comment: What would an "elegant" solution look like, given how browsers work? You want to take an action based on user input: if that action is a style adjustment, or the replacement of textual output with an input form, or ... how else would you do it besides doing it? I'm just trying to understand what exactly you're asking for. It seems like you've already summarized what your code needs to do--the only way it'll do it is if you program it to do so.

Comment: Hey Dave - I agree with what you are saying here.  I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some type of NPM module that I could install that would help facilitate this.  For example I use a lot of drag and drop and there are several NPM modules that facilitate this - dragula is one for example.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something simple and easy.

Comment: There may well be libraries that wrap up stuff like this, but requests for libraries/etc are explicitly OT on SO :) IIRC there are existing post-it note libraries (e.g., https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stickies, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-latest-ui/react-sticky-notes) and tutorials (e.g., https://www.cosmicjs.com/blog/how-to-build-a-sticky-notes-app-using-react-and-redux) so there's a lot of room for re-use, or at least implementation ideas.

Comment: That's really good information Dave.  Please submit this as an answer so I can accept it!  Thanks for the help in talking this through.

Comment: No can (well, no will) do since it's an OT question :) But no prob; hope it helps.